# Creating a new app version with iTMSTransporter

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itmstransporter

I am writing a script that uses the `iTMSTransporter` command-line application to create and upload iOS application metadata for the iOS App Store. However, it's failing in the most bizarre way with little of any helpful information.

```
Apple's web service operation was not successful
Unable to authenticate the package: Benders.itmsp
ERROR ITMS-4157: "Version '2.1.10' is not valid for update or doesn't exist" at Software/SoftwareMetadata (MZItmspSoftwareMetadataPackage)
```

Of course version 2.1.10 doesn't exist--that's what I'm trying to create! Is there some kind of special flag that is needed to create new versions of an app at the command line? I've scoured the `-help` documentation in the tool itself, but can see no such argument.

I feel like I've just run into a brick wall. Googling has turned up nothing.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm concerned it is at the moment not possible to create new versions of your app with the command line tools (iTMSTransporter). You have to do this manually with iTunesconnect. Once the version exists on ITC, you can upload your data with iTMS.

That said the workflow is really bad here, because you cannot do all the important stuff with the command line tool and we are still depending on the moods of ITC.

Comment: Yeah it seems pretty useless to me and is certainly not going to save us much if any time at all. I've instead taken a different route and am now looking into PhantomJS to do headless browser automation. So far it's working like a charm--brilliant tool!

Comment: @chaiguy do you have it somewhere on github/...? I'm pretty interested in automating the app store addition process as much as possible - recently I've created a simple tool for creating xcassets, you can find it here: https://github.com/SzymonFortuna/xcassettool

Comment: @SzymonFortuna I created a github repo for you to see my work in progress. It's not complete but should give you a good idea. https://github.com/chaiguy/ITCBrowserAutomation

Comment: I'm working on some kind of interface to speed up the whole meta data management process. Especially when you got tons of localizations and different apps, uploading (localized) screenshots becomes a huge waste of time. Maybe I can add other steps in the ITC process later on, so we can get rid of ITC after all.

Answer (score 0):

Does the version info you've submitted to Apple match what you've supplied in your package?

See:

- [Submitting the App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingTheApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH33-SW1)
- [Replacing Your App with a New Version](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH14-SW1)

Comment: I haven't submitted the app at all yet, I'm just trying to create the new version's metadata in iTunes Connect.